# Python requests decode using a different charset

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using `requests` to fetch a webpage but the automatically inferred encoding in `response.encoding` is incorrect. I need to decode the bytes in unicode, but I didn't find an API for this. `response.text` is Unicode but not the byte array. Any idea?

Comment: Use .content and decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) (emphasis added):

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the
>   encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding
>   guessed by Requests is used when you access `r.text`. You can find out
>   what encoding Requests is using, and change it, using the `r.encoding`
>   property:
>
> ```
> >>> r.encoding
> 'utf-8'
> >>> r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
> ```
>
> **If you change the encoding, Requests will use the new value of `r.encoding` whenever you call `r.text`**. You might want to do this
>   in any situation where you can apply special logic to work out what
>   the encoding of the content will be. For example, HTTP and XML have
>   the ability to specify their encoding in their body. In situations
>   like this, you should use `r.content` to find the encoding, and then
>   set `r.encoding`. This will let you use `r.text` with the correct
>   encoding.